# If I have user/host pair "root@<MyMachineName>", is it necessary to keep "root@localhost" in the mysql host/users table? (multi-part Q)

Tags: mysql, users, localhost, host

On computer "dexwin10", the user@host pair is as follows:

```
root@dexwin10 

root@% 

root@localhost
```

**When people install our software, we want them to be able to access the database from computers other than just their own.** This tells me localhost should not be given as the hostname, but I'm unsure which of the other two to use.

**Questions:**

1A.) Is `root@dexwin10` the same as `root@localhost` if my computer's name is dexwin10? Or does `root@dexwin10` mean I can only login/access the database from the machine dexwin10, which would make sense since you can only login to root@localhost from the localhost.

B.) If I'm supposed to use `root@dexwin10` and not `root@localhost`, does this mean `root@localhost` can be deleted? Or do I need localhost present to prevent problems?

2.) Should I specify the hostname "%" during our software's installation where it asks us for the hostname containing the database we wish to use, or should I enter "dexwin10"? What could be some side effects of entering just "%" as the hostname?

3.(optional) if `root@(MachineName)` and `root@%` are the same, why doesn't the MySQL installer make the default host whatever your computer's name is, and not some seemingly random string called "localhost"?

I tried to figure out why there were 3 hosts for root (one with my computer name, one with %, and one with localhost) and all the answers are talking about the default mysql users/hosts. These are not the default users.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is a special name.  `name@localhost` implies a "socket" connection.  That can be used *only* from a client on the *same* machine as the mysql server.

Anything else implies a TCP/IP connection, which *may* be to a *different* machine.

When validating a user, the user's name and origin are used to lookup a row in the `GRANT` tables (`mysql.user`, etc).  That is, if you are coming in via TCP/IP, no `localhost` entry is looked at.  And vice versa.

The TCP/IP address for "the current machine" is `127.0.0.1`.  So...

```
mysql -h localhost  -- uses a socket and checks `localhost` entries
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13306  -- uses TCP/IP on same machine
                        (and a non-standard Port)
```

A somewhat 'secure' set of `GRANTs` would include:

```
GRANT ... TO root@localhost ...;  -- you have to get into the machine to use it
_no_ GRANT ... TO root@hostname ...;  -- don't allow access from elsewhere
GRANT ... ON dbname.* TO user@hostname ...;  -- allow a user into one database from anywhere
```

Using `%` (or other wild card specifications) for hostname exposes the server to attacks from arbitrary servers.  Using IP addresses in place of hostnames is slightly more secure.

Also note:

```
CREATE USAGE ON *.* TO root@'%';
```

without any `GRANTs` effectively lets 'root' in from anywhere, but gives him no permissions.  It is sort of a "keep out" sign.

Take a look at

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

and keep in mind that `N` mean "not allowed".  Probably you will see *all* Ns for user=root host=%.  For user=root host=localhost, you will probably see all Ys, including `Grant_priv`, which comes from `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

While I am rambling on, `REVOKE` is half-baked.  You can "revoke"  only *exactly* what was previously `GRANTed`.  You cannot give lots of permissions, then remove a subset.